# Internet connectivity issues

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, connection, internet-connection

My Laptop (a Toshiba Satellite Pro P300 running Vista) is having trouble connecting to my wireless router. Other laptops are using the wireless, but it's not reached capacity. The laptop recognises (with a strong signal) that there is wireless internet, and I can connect via the router with a cable because this happens automatically. My problem is this... When I click "connect" (for example in the network and sharing centre), the dialogue box closes and nothing else happens.

Comment: Is Vista managing the wireless connection or is there a Toshiba application?

Comment: Yeah the Toshiba "ConfigFree" stuff can be annoying as heck. :)